# Is it good to use a ''container'' for objects?

Tags: class, containers

Is it handy to use a single class to ''save'' objects in? Say if I want to use an object many times (the same object), I could easily get it from the ''container class'' that has a static object created.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use containers for containing objects.  If you want to manage a collection of objects, use a container.

Comment: Thank you. I thought using this (instead of passing objects through constructors) is a bad way.

Comment: But will it not use lots of memory because I'am saving objects in 1 class (container) as static (the objects that are made in the container are static)? So memory use is not optimal?

Comment: Do you care?  You haven't said what language or platform so I wouldn't be worrying about "optimal" memory usage.  Add more info to the question for more specific answers.

Comment: Are you saving one object or multiple objects?  If you have something that is only providing an interface to one object, then you could http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: I am saving multiple objects (of multiple classes).

Thank you for those links btw. Always helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for Dependency Injection Pattern. Look for Google Guice for example.

Comment: This seems a little specific and complicated for most simple container patterns.  I've used containers often without the need for Dependency Injection.  FWIW, I would consider the C++ std::vector an good example of a container.

Comment: It seems that user is talking about a container that creates an object. I guess Dependency Injection and Service Locator are the patterns.

Comment: Ah yes, different interpretations.  I guess not enough specific information?  Its hard to tell if the OP is wanting the container to create the object (I hope not), or just store objects.

Comment: after re-reading, it appears that the OP doesn't want to manage collections, so your Dependency Injection pattern is probably pretty good.  You could also potentially use a Bridge http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern